# Which should I reference in NETPortable , can't find GetMethods

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a Portable Classlibrary.

".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile75"

The code

```
typeof(T).GetMethods()
```

with the error

```
cannot resolve symbol 'GetMethods'
```

my project.json

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {

  },
  "frameworks": {
    ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile75": { },
    "net541": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Reflection": "4.1.0-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections.Concurrent": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }

  }
}
```

and the key property in the csproj file

```
  <ProjectTypeGuids>{786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>    
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile75</TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>11.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about that specific profile (and testing anything with that profile is giving me massive errors around predefined types not being available), but I *do* know that reflection is now split between `Type` and `TypeInfo`.

Chances are you want a `using` directive of

```
using System.Reflection;
```

then use:

```
typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods
```

(Using the [`DeclaredMethods` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.declaredmethods(v=vs.110).aspx).) Note that that only returns the methods *declared* in the given class, not inherited ones, which may not be what you need.

or

```
typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetMethods()
```

The latter *claims* to be supported by the PCL, but may not be - in my experience, the version information in MSDN is becoming increasingly hard to trust, with the DNX varieties adding more complexity.

Comment: thank you . typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods is work

Comment: @chsword: Great - so long as you only need the declared methods, of course! It's annoying that I couldn't reproduce it myself... it's never clear to me what the issue is when the predefined types can't be found.

Comment: for example? @Jon Skeet

Comment: @chsword: Well trying just a tiny almost-empty app with your project.json gave me errors along the lines of "Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported" which feels pretty fatal to me. I've verified that Profile75 exists on my machine, so I'm not sure what's wrong...

Comment: visual studio 2015 upgrade to update 1? and make sure the version of dnx .

Comment: @chsword: dnx rc1-final (but not the update to it), and doing it from the command line so VS2015 isn't relevant - although update 1 of that is installed too. Will try the rc1 update...

Comment: @chsword: Same issue after installing rc1-update1 :(

Comment: the portable project target is ".NET Framework 4.5" & "ASP.NET Core 5.0"  @Jon Skeet

Comment: @chsword: Not sure what you mean by that, but I'd assume that as it exists on disk and I've got a copy of your project.json, it should just work. Oh well - not worth worrying about. Glad I was able to fix your issue though!

Answer (score 0):

The example below works for me:

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace mynamespace {
  class MyClass() {
     void test() {
       var tMethods = typeof(DSRObject).DeclaringType.GetRuntimeMethods();
     }
  }
}
```